# reactJS + MongoDB $numberDecimal

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am having issues printing out the `"budget":{"$numberDecimal":"600.00"}` section of my JSON that I have mapped.

Eveything I have tried won't let me print out the $numberDecimal

Tied wrapping it in a Number, Math and even tried what you can see below.

All I get returned is either NaN or [object Object]

```
{data.map((camp, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                  <td colSpan={5}>{camp.campaignName}</td>
                  <td>$140 / {camp.budget.toLocaleString()}</td>
                  <td>Active</td>
                  <td><Button>Edit</Button></td>
                </tr>
                  )
            }
            )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
{camp.budget['$numberDecimal'].toLocaleString()}
```

Comment: It works - but I worked out I could do camp.budget.$numberDecimal and that works as well. Not sure why we have to do it this way.